# Large Scale Woodburning

Tags: wood, burning

Has anyone tried to do woodburning on a large scale with a branding-iron stlye tool?

Looking to make about 100 coasters with same wood-burned image. Since I have foundry equipment, my thought was to cast the design in aluminum and attach to long rod, then heat and stamp each wooden coaster.

Before I embark on the time consuming task of designing, patterning, and casting this "branding iron", I am wondering if anyone else has done something similar and what issues I should beware of beforehand.

Comment: I haven't done this myself but it is widely done. I'm not sure about the feasibility of using aluminium for the 'brand' though, the melting point may be a little low. BTW instead of casting quite a few people today use 3D printing to make this sort of thing which saves a few intermediary steps and usually means they work out cheaper.

Comment: If affordable, use a laser. You can easily just burn the image right into the wood. You can even go as far as light or dark burns to really make the image pop. And a laser can be used to cut out wood (usually 1/2 max.) witch is helpful for some. You can get SMALL ones on Ebay for $300. So there not cheap but very cool.

Comment: @Ljk2000: Second that. Lasers is what producers of cognac (at least one which I happen to know about) use to burn a logo into the thousands of little boxes.

Comment: The idea is to do this without spending any money, it's for a school party that my daughter is helping to plan in the spring. It looks like the only real question is if there is enough thermal energy in an aluminum brand.

Answer (score 1):

There are commercial versions of this branding iron available, either electrically heated or heat-with-torch. The easy-to-find versions are standard "from the workshop of" patterns, but custom is possible, as is homebrew.

I am not convinced that aluminum has the thermal mass needed to do a good job, but it could be an interesting experiment....

Comment: Since I have the aluminum, the foundry, and everything else, the only thing I have to lose is free time by trying it. Other than questioning the thermal energy storage/transfer, no one has said it won't work. So maybe worth a try over the holiday break.